# remove wishlist and product compare from Opencart 1.5

Tags: php, opencart

I am using opencart with journal theme.

Now I no longer want 'wishlist' and 'product compare', so want to disable it.

I tried so many options also tried following link.

1) http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=11879

where it deletes the code for 'wishlist' and 'product compare' using vqmod, but its not working for me with journal theme, and it will never remove the functionality completely.

So how to do this please help me.

Comment: Can't we hide the wishlist, compare buttons and wishlist menu using css or remove the html and javascript part?

Comment: @SankarV we can do that,but its not proper way, so looking for any nice trick

Comment: Remove javascript and html (or hide it using css) related to compare and wishlist code, Add a redirect on the top of wishlist and compare controllers (also for add function) using vqmod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I just wrote a vqmod for this in the last couple of hours. It removes the wishlist and product compare functionality from the 'controller' layer, and also removes it from any of the themes, which are using the default theme's HTML parts. Since I don't know your theme (and the one you've mentioned is a paid-for theme as far as I know), you have to do the necessary modifications yourself, to actually remove the wishlist and compare links from the 'view' layer. But this **might** work if your theme is built upon the default theme. Here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <id>Remove Wishlist and Product Compare</id>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <vqmver>2.4.0</vqmver>
    <author>Tibor Besze</author>

    <file name="catalog/controller/account/account.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['text_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('text_wishlist');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file path="catalog/controller/account/" name="login.php,logout.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[unset($this->session->data['wishlist']);]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/account/wishlist.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[public function index() {]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
                public function index() {
                    $this->redirect($this->url->link('error/not_found', '', 'SSL'));
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[
                public function add() {
            ]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[
                public function add() {
                    $this->redirect($this->url->link('error/not_found', '', 'SSL'));
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/common/footer.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['text_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('text_wishlist');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', 'SSL');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/common/header.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['text_wishlist'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_wishlist'), (isset($this->session->data['wishlist']) ? count($this->session->data['wishlist']) : 0));]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist', '', 'SSL');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/module/account.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['text_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('text_wishlist');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['wishlist'] = $this->url->link('account/wishlist');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file path="catalog/controller/product/" name="category.php,manufacturer.php,search.php,special.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['text_compare'] = sprintf($this->language->get('text_compare'), (isset($this->session->data['compare']) ? count($this->session->data['compare']) : 0));]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['compare'] = $this->url->link('product/compare');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/controller/product/product.php">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['button_wishlist'] = $this->language->get('button_wishlist');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[$this->data['button_compare'] = $this->language->get('button_compare');]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/account/account.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/footer.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>" id="wishlist-total"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a>]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/module/account.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<li><a href="<?php echo $wishlist; ?>"><?php echo $text_wishlist; ?></a></li>]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file path="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/" name="category.tpl,special.tpl,search.tpl,manufacturer_info.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<div class="wishlist"><a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a></div>]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[html += '  <div class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[html += '<div class="wishlist">' + $(element).find('.wishlist').html() + '</div>';]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<div class="product-compare"><a href="<?php echo $compare; ?>" id="compare-total"><?php echo $text_compare; ?></a></div>]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<div class="compare"><a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a></div>]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[html += '  <div class="compare">' + $(element).find('.compare').html() + '</div>';]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[html += '<div class="compare">' + $(element).find('.compare').html() + '</div>';]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

    <file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/product/product.tpl">
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<span class="links"><a onclick="addToWishList('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_wishlist; ?></a><br />]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<a onclick="addToCompare('<?php echo $product_id; ?>');"><?php echo $button_compare; ?></a></span>]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation error="skip">
            <search position="replace"><![CDATA[<span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $text_or; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>]]></search>
            <add trim="true"><![CDATA[]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

</modification>
```

Just put this in an .xml file, and copy it into your vqmod/xml folder. Enjoy!

Comment: I wrote this 2 weeks before Opencart 2.0 has been released, and in my own free time. I don't have time to make it compatible with Opencart 2.0 at the moment, and most likely I won't ever update it. It's just here for educational purposes, not as a copy & paste fully working future-proof solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Journal, you can do this from within the Journal control panel.

Go to Journal -> Settings -> Catalog Mode

From here you can turn the wishlist and compare buttons on or off at various places.